# Bootstrap 3 'img-responsive' class not so responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, image-resizing

**Update:** Here is the latest [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71j5psr0/34/).

---

You'll likely need to resize the **Result** pane, or even break it out into its own window, in order to see it in all its glory.

As you can see, I have a 400x200 logo image that I have *attempted* to make responsive (via the `.img-responsive` class), however it continues to remain the same size (400x200) and is not resizing + nesting nicely into my header navbar.

Ideally the image should resize and fit inside the navbar right in line with the menu items (`MUCH AMAZE`, `SUCH WOW`, etc.).

I have a *feeling* that it has something to do with this part:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" class="img-responsive" height="220" /></a>
</div>
```

I'm not really sure what this "*Toggle navigation*" `<button/>` is doing (the one that comes right before my logo `<img/>`). Admittedly, I am cargo culting here and just got some generic Bootstrap 3 code off their examples site. Am I applying the wrong styling rules? Do I need to put the `<img/>` in a form or div or some other type of container here? Where am I going awry?

Comment: The image is responsive. If you want to fit the image inside the `.navbar-brand` you can remove the height from `.navbar-brand`(`height:auto`).

Comment: Thanks @alirezasafian (+1) - please see my updated jsFiddle. Now the image appears inside the navbar, but is not resizing to fit nicely inside it. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this may help you

```
.img-responsive
{
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anubhav (+1) - how would I add that rule inside the `<img/>` tag?

Comment: either you use inline as <img style="width:100%"> or external bootstrap stylesheet by adding .img-responsive{ width:100%;}